# How to make a proper a Table in Swing as well as put all the elements in their respective positions using a proper layout?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

I am working on a webcrawler and implementing it in several stages.

This stage takes all the links mentioned on a website and shows valid links for webpages with their titles in a JTable.

However, I want the table to be already present before I enter the URL in the TextField to be parsed (that is a requirement of this assignment).

Also, is there a way to fix the current layout (first picture with Macintosh window)
[Current Swing Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpR3Z.jpg)
so that I can correctly display all the JFrame elements in their designated positions as shown in the following picture:

[Desired Swing Window where all elements are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHq6n.jpg)

[image]

I have tried using null layout for fixing the layout issue, it only made the task a nightmare and the table would vanish right before my eyes.

I could not find a way to make the table exist before I even start entering the links.

```
package crawler;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WebCrawler extends JFrame {
    public WebCrawler() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Web Crawler");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(600, 400);

        JTextField urlText = new JTextField();
        urlText.setName("UrlTextField");
//        urlText.setBounds(10,10,300,20);
        urlText.setSize(300,20);

        JLabel title = new JLabel();
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel();
        title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Nueve", Font.BOLD, 12));
        title.setLocation(10,30);
        title.setName("TitleLabel");

        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Nueve", Font.BOLD, 12));
        titleLabel.setText("Title:\t");

        JButton extract = new JButton();
        extract.setText("Parse");
        extract.setName("RunButton");
        extract.setSize(40,20);
        var LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        extract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String url = urlText.getText()/* Get url from JTextField */;
                    url = url.replaceAll("^\"+ \"+$", "");

                    final InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
                    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String nextLine;
                    while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(nextLine);
                        stringBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
                    }


                    final String siteText = stringBuilder.toString();

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<title>(.+?)</title>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(siteText);

                    String titleString = matcher.find()?matcher.group(1):"null";
                    title.setText(titleString);

                    SortedMap<String,String> links = new TreeMap<>();

                    Pattern pTag = Pattern.compile("(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Pattern pLink = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

                    Matcher mTag = pTag.matcher(siteText);


                    try {
                        while (mTag.find()) {

                            String href = mTag.group(1);     // get the values of href
                            String linkElem = mTag.group(2); // get the text of link Html Element

                            Matcher mLink = pLink.matcher(href);

                            while (mLink.find()) {

                                String link = mLink.group(1);

                                link = link.substring(1,link.length()-1);

                                pattern = Pattern.compile("http",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                                matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
                                if(!matcher.find())
                                    link = String.join("",url,link);

                                try {
                                    URL urlValidator = new URL(link);

                                    if(urlValidator.getContent().equals("text/html"));
                                        links.put(link, linkElem);
                                } catch(Exception ex){
                                    System.out.println("Exception encountered at " + link );
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        JTable table = new JTable(toTableModel(links));
                        table.setName("TitlesTable");
                        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                        table.disable();
                        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        table.clearSelection();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
            }
        });
        add(urlText, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(extract, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(title, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        //TODO: change design and layout

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public TableModel toTableModel(Map<?,?>map){
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (
                new Object[] { "URL", "Title" }, 0
        );

        for (Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            model.addRow(new Object[] { entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() });
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

When I run the tests given by the assignment's testing tool, it says "No suitable table element found".

This happens because it needs to detect active table even before it enters the test case URLs into the text field for parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the **JScrollPane** and **JTable** within the **JButton**'s ***ActionPerformed*** event. You can however re-enable the JTable from that event if you like and apply the links to the JTable's model.

If you can, create your Form within a separate class. This cleans things up a great deal since it keeps that form code clutter away from the main task at hand....page scraping for links. A form class might look like this:

```
package webcrawler;

public class Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 101101L;

// Member Variables for Form Components 
public javax.swing.JTextField urlText;
public javax.swing.JButton extract;
public javax.swing.JLabel title;
public javax.swing.JTable table;

private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;

public Form() {
    initializeFormComponents();
    setLookAndFeel();
    openForm();
}

private void setLookAndFeel() {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel if you have it 
       or even like it. Use whatever you like   */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void openForm() {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisible(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
}

private void initializeFormComponents() {
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    urlText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    extract = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    title = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Web Crawler");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("URL:");
    urlText.setName("UrlTextField"); // NOI18N
    extract.setText("Parse");
    extract.setName("RunButton"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(urlText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 667, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(extract, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(urlText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(extract))
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String[]{
                "URL", "TITLE"
            }
    ) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 101110L;
        Class[] types = new Class[]{
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit[columnIndex];
        }
    });
    table.setName("TitlesTable");
    table.setEnabled(false);
    table.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(198,195,195));
    table.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    table.setRowHeight(20);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    titleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12));
    titleLabel.setText("Title:");

    title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12));
    title.setText("None");
    title.setName("TitleLabel");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(scrollPane)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(title, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 348, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(titleLabel)
                                    .addComponent(title))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 478, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
        pack();
    }
}
```

And your WebCrawler Class might then look like this:

```
package webcrawler;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class WebCrawler {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 101011L;
private Form form;
String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // To eliminate the need for statics. I Don't want it right now. 
    new WebCrawler().startApp(args);
}

private void startApp(String[] args) {
    form = new Form();
    form.extract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                clearJTable();  // Clear the JTable
                String url = form.urlText.getText();
                /* Get url from JTextField */
                url = url.replaceAll("^\"+ \"+$", "");

                final InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String nextLine;
                while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(nextLine);
                    stringBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
                }

                final String siteText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<title>(.+?)</title>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(siteText);

                String titleString = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : "null";
                form.title.setText(titleString);

                SortedMap<String, String> links = new TreeMap<>();

                Pattern pTag = Pattern.compile("(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Pattern pLink = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

                Matcher mTag = pTag.matcher(siteText);

                try {
                    while (mTag.find()) {

                        String href = mTag.group(1);     // get the values of href
                        String linkElem = mTag.group(2); // get the text of link Html Element

                        Matcher mLink = pLink.matcher(href);

                        while (mLink.find()) {
                            String link = mLink.group(1);
                            link = link.substring(1, link.length() - 1);
                            pattern = Pattern.compile("http", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                            matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
                            if (!matcher.find()) {
                                link = String.join("", url, link);
                            }
                            try {
                                //URL urlValidator = new URL(link);
                                //if (urlValidator.getContent().equals("text/html")) {
                                links.put(link, linkElem);
                                //}
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex);
                                //System.out.println("Exception encountered at " + link);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    form.table.setEnabled(true);    // Enable JTable
                    form.table.setModel(toTableModel(links));
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            // Is there anything in the table?
            if (form.table.getModel().getRowCount() == 0) {
                // NOPE...So Disable JTable.
                form.table.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
    form.urlText.requestFocus();
}

private void clearJTable() {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) form.table.getModel();
    while (tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tableModel.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
    // Reset 4 blank rows in the table for looks :) 
    form.table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{{null, null}, {null, null}, {null, null},{null, null}},
            new String[]{"<html><font color=blue><b>U R L</b></font></html>", 
                         "<html><font color=red><b>T I T L E</b></font></html>"}));
    // Yes...you can use basic HTML in a JTable Header.
}

public TableModel toTableModel(Map<?, ?> map) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[]{"URL", "TITLE"}, 0
    );
    for (Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()});
    }
    return model;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the table to be already present before I enter the URL

Then you need to create and add an empty table to the frame at the same time you create and add all the other components to the frame.

You need to create an instance variable for your JTable to you can modify its model.

The code to add the table to the frame would be something like:

```
add(title, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (new Object[] { "URL", "Title" }, 0);
table = new JTable( model );
add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So now you will see an empty table with just the columns when you start the app.

The code in your `toTableModel(...)` method now becomes something like:

```
//DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (new Object[] { "URL", "Title" }, 0);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```

Which just removes all the rows in the model so your looping code can add each new row of data.

And of course you would also remove the code in your ActionListener where you currently create the JTable and JScrollPane, since it is no longer required.

> Also, is there a way to fix the current layout

Your nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desire effect.

For example you want the table to be able to grow/shrink depending on the data in the table so it should be added to the `CENTER` of your `BorderLayout`.

However the top to two rows are fixed to they should be added to a child panel. Then this panel would be added to the `PAGE_START` of your `BorderLayout. Maybe a vertical`BoxLayout`.

Then each row is another child panel. The first row could be a panel with a horizontal `BoxLayout` and the second row a panel with a `FlowLayout`.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), Then you logically group component on child panels using an appropriate layout manager.